# React.js DOM element not displayed

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, jsx, ant-design-pro

im trying to mount a DOM element to a div but for some reason it does not work, page is blank. Im using react, vs code and antdesign library. App was created with npm (create react app). Sandbox link with working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/scrolling-loaded-antd4151-forked-p6qmp?file=/index.html

This is my code:

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
    <meta
      name="description"
      content="Web site created using create-react-app"
    />
    <title>React App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <div id='test-container'/>
    <script>var mountNode = document.getElementById('test-container');</script>
  </body>
</html>
```

index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
import './index.css';

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
reportWebVitals();
```

test.js

```
import React from 'react'
import InfiniteScroll from 'react';
import reqwest from 'reqwest';
import { List, message, Avatar, Spin } from 'antd';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import 'antd/dist/antd.css';

const fakeDataUrl = 'https://randomuser.me/api/?results=5&inc=name,gender,email,nat&noinfo';

class InfiniteListExample extends React.Component {
  state = {
    data: [],
    loading: false,
    hasMore: true,
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchData(res => {
      this.setState({
        data: res.results,
      });
    });
  }

  fetchData = callback => {
    reqwest({
      url: fakeDataUrl,
      type: 'json',
      method: 'get',
      contentType: 'application/json',
      success: res => {
        callback(res);
      },
    });
  };

  handleInfiniteOnLoad = () => {
    let { data } = this.state;
    this.setState({
      loading: true,
    });
    if (data.length > 14) {
      message.warning('Infinite List loaded all');
      this.setState({
        hasMore: false,
        loading: false,
      });
      return;
    }
    this.fetchData(res => {
      data = data.concat(res.results);
      this.setState({
        data,
        loading: false,
      });
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="demo-infinite-container">
        <InfiniteScroll
          initialLoad={false}
          pageStart={0}
          loadMore={this.handleInfiniteOnLoad}
          hasMore={!this.state.loading && this.state.hasMore}
          useWindow={false}
        >
          <List
            dataSource={this.state.data}
            renderItem={item => (
              <List.Item key={item.id}>
                <List.Item.Meta
                  avatar={
                    <Avatar src="https://zos.alipayobjects.com/rmsportal/ODTLcjxAfvqbxHnVXCYX.png" />
                  }
                  title={<a href="https://ant.design">{item.name.last}</a>}
                  description={item.email}
                />
                <div>Content</div>
              </List.Item>
            )}
          >
            {this.state.loading && this.state.hasMore && (
              <div className="demo-loading-container">
                <Spin />
              </div>
            )}
          </List>
        </InfiniteScroll>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<InfiniteListExample />, document.getElementById('test-container'));
```

app.js

```
import './App.css';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks for your help

Comment: It's normal because your App render is blank, try to put some text inside your ```<div className="App">some text</div>```

Comment: but why isnt the infinite list example loaded ? The one I mounted in the test-container

Comment: Because you don't import it in your main entry file index.js

Answer (score 0):

You should import InfiniteListExample instead of App component (index.js file)

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import InfiniteListExample from './test';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
import './index.css';

ReactDOM.render(<InfiniteListExample />, document.getElementById('root'));
reportWebVitals();
```

and remove the call of ReactDOM from your test.js file

```
import React from 'react'
import InfiniteScroll from "react-infinite-scroller";
import reqwest from 'reqwest';
import { List, message, Avatar, Spin } from 'antd';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import 'antd/dist/antd.css';

const fakeDataUrl = 'https://randomuser.me/api/?results=5&inc=name,gender,email,nat&noinfo';

class InfiniteListExample extends React.Component {
  state = {
    data: [],
    loading: false,
    hasMore: true,
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchData(res => {
      this.setState({
        data: res.results,
      });
    });
  }

  fetchData = callback => {
    reqwest({
      url: fakeDataUrl,
      type: 'json',
      method: 'get',
      contentType: 'application/json',
      success: res => {
        callback(res);
      },
    });
  };

  handleInfiniteOnLoad = () => {
    let { data } = this.state;
    this.setState({
      loading: true,
    });
    if (data.length > 14) {
      message.warning('Infinite List loaded all');
      this.setState({
        hasMore: false,
        loading: false,
      });
      return;
    }
    this.fetchData(res => {
      data = data.concat(res.results);
      this.setState({
        data,
        loading: false,
      });
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="demo-infinite-container">
        <InfiniteScroll
          initialLoad={false}
          pageStart={0}
          loadMore={this.handleInfiniteOnLoad}
          hasMore={!this.state.loading && this.state.hasMore}
          useWindow={false}
        >
          <List
            dataSource={this.state.data}
            renderItem={item => (
              <List.Item key={item.id}>
                <List.Item.Meta
                  avatar={
                    <Avatar src="https://zos.alipayobjects.com/rmsportal/ODTLcjxAfvqbxHnVXCYX.png" />
                  }
                  title={<a href="https://ant.design">{item.name.last}</a>}
                  description={item.email}
                />
                <div>Content</div>
              </List.Item>
            )}
          >
            {this.state.loading && this.state.hasMore && (
              <div className="demo-loading-container">
                <Spin />
              </div>
            )}
          </List>
        </InfiniteScroll>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default InfiniteListExample;
```

Comment: I tried this and I get an error

Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.

Comment: did you add ```export default InfiniteListExample;``` in your test.js file?

Comment: I did an update, please try it,( the ```import InfiniteScroll from 'react';```  is not correct, it should be ```import InfiniteScroll from 'react-infinite-scroller' ``` instead)

Comment: thanks but I already figured it out, posted the anwser few minutes before you right below

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue..

I installed react-infinite-scroller but when I did it, I was not in project root directory but inside react directory. It did install it successfully and everything seemed fine since import was pointing correctly. I deleted the package, installed it from root, changed

```
import InfiniteScroll from 'react';
```

to

```
import InfiniteScroll from 'react-infinite-scroller';
```

and it started working. Strangely the vs code debugger didn't complain...